# Android Studio - Google Maps Search

Tags: android, google-maps

I wanted to implement a method like the google search map where the user types in an address, hits a button and is taken to the address they give, is there any where i can read about that online thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Check this out from Google's official documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

If you like video tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc

If you just want to launch the Google Maps app:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

> Use this intent to display search queries within a specified viewport. When the query has a single result, you can use this intent to display a pin at a particular place or address, such as a landmark, business, geographic feature, or town.

```
geo:latitude,longitude?q=query
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=latitude,longitude(label)
```

More at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using android studio, there should be a template for google maps, it will make your job a whole lot easier. That is what I do in most of my google maps related project Here is a tutorial on youtube that explains android google maps in a good way - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-LW0DinKrk